# How is it possible that Filter is applied when its dispatcher is FORWARD as well as when dispatcher is REQUEST?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, dispatcher

I have a simple Filter:

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("before");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        System.out.println("after");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

It's the first filter in web.xml and it has one of these two mappings:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cookie-test-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

or

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cookie-test-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

In both cases I see the output:

```
before
before
after
after
```

(I've also tried `INCLUDE` as dispatcher just to be sure that everything works - there's no output with `INCLUDE`).

There're 3rd-party filters and servlets after this filter and I wonder: what should they do to make my filter applied in both described cases?

Comment: Which app server, including its version, are you using? In your web.xml, what is the value for the `web-app` element's `version` attribute?

Comment: @kschneid: Apache Tomcat 6.0.30, web-app version="2.4"

Comment: Are you sure that there's only one filter mapping in `web.xml`? This can happen when you've two mappings of the same filter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a single `<filter-mapping>` entry with both **REQUEST** and **FORWARD** dispatcher

**Example**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cookie-test-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Hope this clears up the issue you were having.