# Java Filter using Request Dispatcher - using JavaEE 6 Annotations

Tags: java, java-ee-6, servlet-filters, dispatcher

I have created a filter for "/folder/*" using the JaveEE 6 Annotation

```
@WebFilter("/folder/*")
```

However when I go to "/test.html" which has a call

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/folder/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

in the doGet, the page is not filtered. When going to "/folder/test.jsp" manually in the browser, the filter works fine. How can I make it work when using a dispatcher also?

I have found a solution for the xml way of creating filters multiple places such as [here](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=34168) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325405/how-is-it-possible-that-filter-is-applied-when-its-dispatcher-is-forward-as-well) but have been unable to find a solution using annotations. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The annotations seems to have a [dispatcherTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html#dispatcherTypes()) attribute to support this, so the following should work:

```
@WebFilter(value={"/folder/*"},
           dispatcherTypes={DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD})
```