# Get jsp content after forward

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can I get content of a jsp page, after servlet made a forward. At them moment I'm trying the following:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(DESTINATION_PAGE).forward(request, response);
URL teamsURL = new URL(request.getScheme(), request.getServerName(), request.getServerPort(), request.getContextPath() + DESTINATION_PAGE);
URLConnection teamsCon = teamsURL.openConnection();
String fileName = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".html";
System.out.println(fileName);
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(teamsCon.getInputStream()));
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName)) {
    String inputLine = null;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(inputLine);
    }
}
```

I get the html with empty divs. But, I want the same page I see in browser.

Sorry for messy post, ask for what info you need, I'll update my post accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand. You forward the request then you write to a file. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to save resulting page to a file after executing my servlet.

Comment: that is not a forward

Comment: So how it should look? I have a few attributes, so i guess redirect cant be used?

Comment: do a google search for forward and redirect, they aren't the same

Comment: how can it help with my problem? I mean i cant use redirect because i need to pass an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get the response body after you've written it, you'll need to use a custom `HttpServletResponse` wrapper that keeps track of what was written to the `OutputStream` directly or with the `Writer`.

You will do this in a servlet `Filter` after `chain.doFilter(request, yourResponseWrapper)` returns. A simple example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701681/how-can-i-read-an-httpservletreponses-output-stream/702392#702392).

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to map this filter to a jsp which is called via forward? Or do i have to move all my logic from a servlet to a filter?

Comment: @Azaro You can setup your filter to only work on forwards. I would suggest you mix that with a `url-pattern` that matches your `Servlet`'s.

Comment: Can u link me an example of filter that works on forward? Cant find it.

Comment: @Azaro Take a look at some other answers, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325405/how-is-it-possible-that-filter-is-applied-when-its-dispatcher-is-forward-as-well).

Comment: Last question, so the part in the filter after chain.doFilter() is called after servlet? I made forward in servlet(returns blank html page, but file is full) and then redirect in filter to the created file, is that a right approach?

Comment: @azaro Yes, `chain.doFilter` will execute the `Servlet` down the line.  If you do a `forward`, I THINK that you will reenter the `Filter` body.

Comment: Thanks man, i would love to +1 you, but i dont have enough rep.